# Is using a screenshot of Google Maps on a company's website allowed?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to use a screenshot of Google Maps on my company's website. But I'm not sure they allow using the maps besides through their API. Maybe it's OK if the image points to the Google website?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It isn't allowed. You have to use the Google Maps API or ask for a High Res Screenshot directly to Google.com

link -> http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

Comment: http://www.openstreetmap.org has a more permissive license. See "How to credit OpenStreetMap" at http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright

Comment: Which section of that permission documentation actually says it's not allowed? The page currently says `Google Earth Pro lets you print high-resolution views`, but it doesn't say you can't do the same independently as far as I see.

Comment: Yeah, I’d only accept this answer myself if there was a reference to the section which directly prohibits the type of use described in the question. I’d probably still consult a lawyer before going against the answer’s advice.

Comment: Consider that the answer ot 8 years ago could be wrong nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a screenshot if you include attribution visible to the average reader. The attribution must be in conjunction with the screenshot, not at the bottom of the page. See https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html

Comment: This conflicts with Baronth's accepted answer which cites the same webpage. Can you include a quote for which part of the page says it can be used with attribution?

Comment: Consider that the answer ot 8 years ago could be wrong nowadays

Comment: Currently the linked page explicitly says screenshots are allowed:
_"If neither of those fit your needs, you may export an image from Google Earth or Earth Studio, or capture a screenshot from Google Maps, to add custom labels or graphics using third-party software."_


But it also says that they require attribution:
_"All uses of Google Maps, Google Earth, and Street View content must provide attribution to Google and, if applicable, to our data providers."_

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Google Maps image if you give **attribution** in the way they want it.

Found on [Permissions - Google](http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html)

> ## Using Google Maps, Google Earth and Street View
>
> [...]
>
> ### general guidelines
>
> [...]
>
> #### Attribution
>
> All uses of the Content must provide attribution to both Google and our data providers. We require clear, visible attribution when the Content is shown. You may not move the attribution to the end credits or fade it out after a few seconds.
>
> Note that if you embed a classic map, Street View panorama or My Map; use one of our APIs on the web or in an application; or export a video or JPEG from Google Earth Pro, the necessary attribution is already baked into the map and no further credit is needed. Learn more about how to properly credit, as well as how to identify providers, on our attribution guidelines page
>
> If you are unwilling to meet our attribution requirements, contact our data provider(s) directly to inquire about purchasing the rights to use the Content directly. You’ll find provider contact information listed on their websites.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that just related to images from Google Earth, not to screenshots of mapping data from Google Maps, which is what the original question asked about.